# Eclipse shows up non informing parameter names with ASM 4.0. How to fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-bytecode-asm

When using ASM 4.0 from the Eclipse IDE, all I get are these non informing parameter names:
[image]

How can I fix this? I've had a look in the past to part of the source code of the library and from what I recall, they seemed to have genuine names, so I guess this must be something I haven't loaded?

**R: attaching the JavaDoc seemed to solve the variable name's problem.** There is still a small mystery to clarify, though:

When using the API, it does look as ClassNode.methods is of type List. But in truth, looking at its source code, we see that it actually is a List:

```
/**
 * The methods of this class. This list is a list of {@link MethodNode}
 * objects.
 *
 * @associates org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode
 */
public List<MethodNode> methods;
```

Is there any other thing I am missing? I am aware that maybe the problem could be related with Java's lack of generics reification, needing some other kind of intel to know what these lists actually represent?

[image]

Comment: attache the source to the asm.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using asm-all-debug.jar in the IDE should solve all those issues. Generics info is erased from the optimized asm.jar to make it smaller.